# PostgreSQL plpgsql try catch block equivalent

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.

I have a `PROCEDURE` in sql server. That makes use of a `try catch` block. It looks a little bit like the code below:

```
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
        --do stuff here
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        --do error stuff here
        END CATCH
```

Upon doing some research, It seems like postgres does not make use of `try catch`. Is there some way to handle this in postgres the same way sql server does?

Comment: It is `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` in PL/pgSQL. But you cannot commit in a function.

Comment: so all functions autocommit?

Comment: No; every function runs inside a single transaction (of course several functions can run in te same transaction, but you cannot commit or rollback inside a function). PostgreSQL v11 changes that.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: See this answer from [stack exchange database admins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244328/try-catch-equivalent-in-postgres)